# Composable Not Collecting Updated Value in StateFlow

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

I have a form screen written in Compose where the user can fill out some `TextField`s and submit it. If they press the submit button before filling out the fields, the supporting text for the empty `TextField`s will change to say "Required".

[Required text on empty fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9bfM.png)

To do this, I've created a `ViewState` that includes a `showRequired` field:

```
data class ViewState(
    showRequired: Boolean = false,
    // other fields
)
```

In my view model, I create a `MutableStateFlow` with the `ViewState` as its default value:

```
private val _viewState: MutableStateFlow<ViewState> = MutableStateFlow(ViewState())
val viewState: StateFlow<viewState> = _viewState.asStateFlow()
```

To have the composable show the required message, I update the view state like this:

```
fun onSubmitClicked(form: Form) {
    if (areRequiredFieldsMissing(form)) {
        _viewState.update { it.copy(showRequired = true) }
    }
}
```

In my composable, I'm collecting that flow with `collectAsStateWithLifecycle()` and then checking if `showRequired = true` before showing the message:

```
val viewState = viewModel.viewState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

if (viewState.value.showRequired) {
    // set supportingText = Required
}
```

When I click the submit button, the message shows as expected. However, if I leave this screen and then come back to it, the required message shows by default instead of being hidden. I thought I could fix this by updating the view state when the back button is pressed to set `showRequired = false`:

```
// in my view model
fun onBackPressed() {
    _viewState.update { it.copy(showRequired = false) }
}
```

However this doesn't fix anything. When I come back to the form screen, the required message still shows by default. When I debug the composable, the value collected for `showRequired` is still true. Why doesn't updating it to false work correctly, but updating it to true when clicking the submit button does? I think I'm misunderstanding how `StateFlow` works but I'm not sure what to try.

EDIT: I resolved this by resetting my `ViewState` when exiting the screen so that `showRequired` is reset to false, instead of just updating it.

```
_viewState.value = ViewState()
```

Comment: Are you using the same ViewModel for both screens? How is `onBackPressed` called?

Comment: Yes I'm using the same ViewModel (confirmed it's the same instance). My form page uses a `Scaffold` with a `TopAppBar` that has a navigation icon with an `onClick` specified. When I click the navigation icon, the view model's `onBackPressed()` is invoked.

Comment: Hi, check if my answer solves your problem. Kindly accept & upvote the answer if it does.

Answer (score 0):

`showRequired` should be a separate SharedFlow shouldn't keep in state as StateFlow, showing a message when there is an empty field on submit is an event not a state, you should show it only once. StateFlow is keeping its value and when you come back from a different screen recomposition occurs and

```
val viewState = viewModel.viewState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

if (viewState.value.showRequired) {
    // show message
}
```

this code block gets executed again, and because `showRequired` in state is set true message will be shown.

You should remove `showRequired` from your viewState

```
private val _formWarningEvent = MutableSharedFlow<Boolean>()
val formWarningEvent = _formWarningEvent.asSharedFlow()
```

in Composable

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    viewModel.formWarningEvent.onEach { show -> // can register lifecycle or use collect etc.
        if (show) // show message
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain what I'm doing correctly. I'm not just showing a one-off thing like a Toast message. The input fields are `TextField`s, and I change their supporting text to say "Required" when the submit button is clicked but they're empty. In this case, that would be a state change, so `StateFlow` is appropriate, right? I've updated the post with a screenshot showing what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding of the use case.
Add a comment if it is not exactly the same.

You have a screen with multiple `TextFields` and a Submit `Button`. On clicking the submit button, the app navigates to a different screen.
The states are maintained in a shared ViewModel between screens.
The error message is to be shown only after the user clicks on the button, but validation fails.

My first suggestion would be to use screen level `ViewModel` instead of shared  `ViewModel` which automatically clears the states when it is removed.

But, there may be scenarios where that is not possible. In that case, you can try this,

**ViewModel**

```
// To store the state of the TextField input
private val _textFieldState: MutableStateFlow<String> = MutableStateFlow("")
val textFieldState: StateFlow<String> = _viewState.asStateFlow()

// To store the state of the CTA button click
private val _ctaClicked: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(false)
val ctaClicked: StateFlow<Boolean> = _viewState.asStateFlow()

// To store the state of the CTA button click
private val textFieldErrorState: MutableStateFlow<String?> = combine(
    textFieldState,
    ctaClicked,
) { textFieldState, ctaClicked, ->
    if (ctaClicked && textFieldState.isEmpty()) {
        "Required"
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

We are using `combine` from Kotlin to listen to both the `TextField` input state as well as the CTA button click state.

You should reset the `ctaClicked` when navigating away from the screen.

Comment with more details, if this is not working for your use-case.

Comment: I need the view model to be shared because it emits a snackbar message that the previous screen needs to collect and show. I fixed this by resetting my `ViewState` when leaving the screen so that `showRequired` gets reset to false.